# Access 2010 Strange behavior

Tags: sql, ms-access

Goodmorning everybody, I'm doing a query in Access 2010 and I'm getting a strange behavior, so I'd like to hear your opinion, here we go:

```
SELECT X.*, L.CodLinea
FROM (
   SELECT TOP 1 'LBASE' AS CodLinea, 'Linea Base' AS Descrizione FROM ParametriAzienda
)  AS X LEFT JOIN Linee AS L 
ON X.CodLinea = L.CodLinea
```

The inner query gives always ONE row with two colums that should be something like:

```
CodLinea  |  Descrizione
----------+--------------
  LBASE   |  Linea Base
```

Now, doing a left join like above should return ONE row with another column called L.CodLinea with a value that is EQUAL to 'LBASE' or NULL depending if the table Linee has got 'LBASE' inside. So, the result can be:

```
  X.CodLinea  |  X.Descrizione  |  L.CodLinea
+-------------+-----------------+--------------+
    LBASE     |  Linea Base     |   LBASE
```

if the value exists, or

```
  X.CodLinea  |  X.Descrizione  |  L.CodLinea
+-------------+-----------------+--------------+
    LBASE     |  Linea Base     |   null
```

if the value doesn't exist. Indeed what I get is:

```
  X.CodLinea  |  X.Descrizione  |  L.CodLinea
+-------------+-----------------+--------------+
    LBASE     |  Linea Base     |   0          
    LBASE     |  Linea Base     |   0          
    LBASE     |  Linea Base     |   0          
    LBASE     |  Linea Base     |   0          
    LBASE     |  Linea Base     |   0
```

That definitely can't be possible, becasue: a) I should get only one row; b) 0 is NOT equal or like to LBASE. If I use the WHERE instead of LEFT JOIN (similar to an INNER JOIN) the or a RIGHT JOIN, the results are correct (0 rows).

What can be the matter?

EDIT: Actually ParametriAzienda has got only one row and Linee does not contain LBASE value.

Comment: I also tested this on Jet 4.0 (.mdb) and got the same results i.e. this is not problem specifically with Access 2010 nor ACE (.accdb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `TOP 1`: either you have misunderstood its use (bug in your code) or it's a bug in the engine.

Personally, I always use `DISTINCT` because it is Standard SQL (and I understand its use :) Indeed, when I tested this, replacing `TOP 1` with `DISTINCT` turns your actual result into the expected result.

Here's my repro. The below VBA creates a new data file in temp folder, with tables and sample data. No references required, simply copy+paste into any VBA module e.g. use Excel:

```
Sub NotTop1()

  On Error Resume Next
  Kill Environ$("temp") & "\DropMe.accdb"
  On Error GoTo 0

  Dim cat
  Set cat = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")

  With cat
  .Create _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & _
        Environ$("temp") & "\DropMe.accdb"

    With .ActiveConnection

      Dim Sql As String

      Sql = _
      "CREATE TABLE ParametriAzienda (x INTEGER NOT NULL);"
      .Execute Sql

      Sql = _
      "INSERT INTO ParametriAzienda (x) VALUES (1);"
      .Execute Sql

      Sql = _
      "CREATE TABLE Linee (CodLinea CHAR(1) NOT NULL);"
      .Execute Sql

      Dim i As Long
      For i = 0 To 4
        Sql = _
        "INSERT INTO Linee (CodLinea) VALUES ('0');"
        .Execute Sql
      Next

      Sql = _
      "SELECT X.*, L.CodLinea " & _
      "FROM ( " & _
      "   SELECT TOP 1 'LBASE' AS CodLinea, 'Linea Base' AS Descrizione FROM ParametriAzienda " & _
      ")  AS X LEFT JOIN Linee AS L  " & _
      "ON X.CodLinea = L.CodLinea"

  Dim rs
  Set rs = .Execute(Sql)
  MsgBox rs.GetString(2, , vbTab & vbTab, , "<null>")

  Sql = Replace$(Sql, "TOP 1", "DISTINCT")

  Set rs = .Execute(Sql)
  MsgBox rs.GetString(2, , vbTab & vbTab, , "<null>")        
    End With
    Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Uhm, I guess this is not the problem. We've tried without TOP 1 and it still gets 5 rows, so does DISTINCT. Actually, ParametriAzienda has only one row...

Comment: @IssamTP: Did you try running my code? Do you get different results? If not, can you change my code to better reflect your scenario? e.g. perhaps your data is radically different, you have only provided hints at what it might actually be.

Comment: I'll let you know, also I've added some infos about the db data.

Comment: @IssamTP: note my data already satisfies the condition you just added ("ParametriAzienda has got only one row and Linee does not contain LBASE value").

Comment: I've tested your code, and, man you're a genius, it works. Indeed, when I first ask to my workmate to change TOP 1 with DISTINCT he misunderstood me and he put DISTINCT on the outer query.